# Apply jquery function to added element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the workflow:

1. Add elements dynamically to a div container
2. Register click event for this elements (using jquery custom function)
3. Trigger the element event

According to the flow above, I can't get the new element event works, because it never is triggered. This is my scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ru76/1/

The idea is that when you click over "element" its ID attribute should be printed in .log div

Edit:

I have tested all answers and all of them work fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsFiddle, the code is automatically put in a `$(document).ready` block.  So, what's happening is your `$(document).ready` is ran immediately.  This means it's ran *before* `jQuery.fn.showID` is set.

Also, `$(".element").showID();​` binds the event to `.element`s that exist at that time.  New elements won't have the event bound.  You need to either use event delegation (which makes the `showID` plugin useless), or call `showID` after adding the element (making sure not to re-bind to old elements).

P.S. Inside a jQuery plugin `this` is already a jQuery object, no need to use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

You had the `$(".element").showID();` outside the `.create` click handler so there was nothing to select, also you had your code in onLoad when it should be in no-wrap head.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ru76/9/

Comment: Each call to `showID` will re-bind the event to the previous elements.

Comment: @Rocket I added a filter to select only the last one will bind a handler but then the ids are duplicate and the process could be done more efficiently.

Comment: FYI: the id is generated by another function that have no importance in this scenario

Comment: You can also create the new element first, bind the event, then use appendTo.  That way, the events wouldn't get re-bound.  http://jsfiddle.net/9Ru76/10/

Comment: @Rocket, nice trick: `.showID().appendTo(`. Now suppose that `.element` elements are already added becasue they come from `removeClass('something').addClass('.element')`. In this case, Does the event delegation works as the same way?  PS: Do I need to open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".create").click(function(){
         $(".container").append('<div id="4" href="#" class="element">element</div>');
    });
});


    $(document).on('click','.element', function(){
        $(".log").html("id: " + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
```